# LibreOffice stopped working in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: libreoffice, shared-library

After upgrading to 17.04, when I start LibreOffice, I get the following error messages:

```
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to completely remove and reinstall the `libreoffice` package. I've checked and there are no PPAs in the sources list.

Update: turns out the file `libreglo.so` exists in directory `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/`. When I add this directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` LibreOffice works. But why is it apparently mis-configured by default?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `echo "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`?

Comment: Your solution fixed that specific error for me, but still didn't fix Libre, which gives me the different error: `The component manager is not available.
("Cannot open uno ini file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/unorc at /build/libreoffice-3GTqhx/libreoffice-7.5.4~rc2/cppuhelper/source/defaultbootstrap.cxx:53")`

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem after upgrading. This solution (by disabling java) worked for me:

[LibreOffice 5 problems and solutions](https://blog.softhints.com/libre-office-5-problems-and-solutions/)

Open LibreOffice or any program - Writer, Calc (only one program, settings apply to the whole suite)

- Go to **Options**
- **LibreOffice**
- **Advanced**
- Uncheck "Use a Java runtime environment"

Comment: +1 since I assume LibreOffice will *mostly* work with java disabled, but I don't think this is an ideal solution long term. Is there a bug report for this?

Comment: I'm not sure is there a bug report. I know that it's a workaround but so far it was the only one that work for me. I hope that next updates will fix it.

Comment: I'm sure your answer will help lots of people in the meantime - I guess folks should try re-enabling java after each update if it doesn't happen automatically

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem with Ubuntu Artful 17.10. All of the libreoffice programs produced the error listed. Disabling Java made no difference. I tried purging and re-installing Libreoffice and even purging and switching back from the [LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to the default Ubuntu repository did not solve the problem. I also tried removing the libreoffice configuration files in ~/.config

It is clear that LibreOffice is not finding it's libraries and [this post](https://www.questarter.com/q/ubuntu-17-04-libreoffice-stopped-working-3_913812.html) set me on the right path to sorting out  the library path.  Unfortunately simply adding `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program` to LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not enough.  LibreOffice still would not run.  For me, I had to make sure that `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program` was the first library directory that LibreOffice looked at.  For bash, this meant adding the following line to the end of `.bashrc`

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

and for the UI, it meant editing

`/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop`

and replacing

```
Exec=libreoffice --writer %U
```

with

```
Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ libreoffice --writer %U
```

My naive assumption is that there are some duplicate libraries in LibreOffice and they need their particular flavour to be loaded in order to run.

Comment: I confirm that with Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia, with kernel 5.3.0-25-generic on x64 the same problem exists. The setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to proper path (/usr/lib/libreoffice/program) did not work when it was set at the end of the variable. When run with variable set at the start of the command as shown in Exec above, it suddenly works as usual.

Comment: I found the same problem in launching libreoffice from the command line in `18.04`, and it is resolved by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to start with `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not enough to modify lines with `%U`. This modifies both necessary lines:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo su
# enter password
for i in libre*.desktop; do sed -i 's/Exec=libreoffice/Exec=env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:\/usr\/lib\/libreoffice\/program:\/usr\/lib\/x86_64-linux-gnu\/ libreoffice/g' $i; done
exit
```

Comment: despite this fix, installing mendeley plugin was almost impossible

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have found is to edit the shell-script /usr/bin/soffice and add on the beginning (after the 1st block of comments):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by purging the libreoffice installation

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
```

I deleted the directories

```
/var/lib/libreoffice
/etc/libreoffice
```

I then installed libreoffice as a snap

```
sudo snap install libreoffice
```