# Libreoffice error: libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file

Tags: apt, 20.04, libreoffice, shared-library, mendeley

Got this error after installing libreoffice 7.2.3 in Ubuntu 20.04 using apt:

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Here's the output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice`:

```
libreoffice:
  Installed: 1:7.2.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1
  Candidate: 1:7.2.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.2.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.1.7-0ubuntu0.21.04.1~bpo20.04.1 100
        100 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     1:6.4.2-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libreoffice` to the question. FYI 20.04 LTS is shipped [with 6.4.7](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libreoffice), so you are using some PPA or third-party repository. When the message "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.63: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory." appeared?

Comment: You're right about the ppa. I'm not sure what I did for it to get there, since it's been a long time since I had this error.. Thanks @N0rbert.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (inspired from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913812/libreoffice-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-17-04/1374700#1374700)) is to insert the following two lines under the comment lines in "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice" and in "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/unopkg" to get both libreoffice and Mendeley working.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Don't put SOLVED in the question title here, please. Mark your answer as solved instead.

Comment: Thanks @OrganicMarble. Seems it has been done already.