# libreoffice suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu MATE 22.04.03 LTS

Tags: libreoffice, mate

Hello I have  Ubuntu MATE 22.04.03 LTS on a desktop computer.
Today, suddenly, I cannot run any libreoffice program anymore. I get this error:

```
$ lowriter 
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? Where should i get this file `libreglo.so` which apparently is missing?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is a solution or a workaround, however libreoffice seems to work again after inserting `/usr/lib/libreoffice/program` at the first place in the shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
So inserted this line in my `~/.profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

After restart Libreoffice seems to work.

I found this suggestion here:

[LibreOffice stopped working in Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913812/libreoffice-stopped-working-in-ubuntu-17-04)

Comment: Interesting, looks like others have been having the same near-duplicate problem for a while, only now the file is actually missing in addition to being mis-configured somehow.

Comment: Strange. On a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install, this variable does not appear to be set. I also do not see it on Fedora. Is this a default install of LibreOffice?

Comment: No, it worked without problems until the other day. Maybe some recent installations i made generated conflicts, but now it is difficult for me to investigate this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your **uno-libs-private** package may be missing or has some corrupted files... it supplies the libreglo.so file (at /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libreglo.so ).

Reinstalling that package should get the file back in the right place... assuming you don't already have the file. First you can check with a find:

```
find / -mount -iname "*libreglo.so*" 2>/dev/null
```

And if it doesn't find the file then give this a try: `apt reinstall uno-libs-private`

If the file is already on your system, it could still be corrupted and a reinstall *should* fix it. Or maybe something else has gone wrong with libreoffice, and it can't find the file... Maybe reinstalling all the libreoffice packages would help, or if not that sounds like a libreoffice bug...?

---

FYI, here's how I reached my conclusion:

I've got libreoffice installed and working, I tried the find command listed above, then `dpkg -S [full path for file]` to find what package supplies it.

Comment: HI thank you! I didn't in fact have that file, and after reinstalling uno-libs-private it appeared in the /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/ directory. However this was not enough, I had to put the path of that directory in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. I posted an answer explaining this

Comment: I guess LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set by default (the system searches in the default directories, including /usr/lib. On your system, the variable appears to have been set to a different directory, so default directories are not anymore searched.